# ReferenceError: ExtRemote is not defined Ext.direct.Manager.addProvider(ExtRemote.REMOTING_API);

Tags: node.js, ext-direct

js, and willing to learn using extdirect I followed the documentation included  in the node-module and this page: npmjs.org/package/extdirect, that are exactly the same thing, when I point firefox to the index.html I got this error at my app.js line 6:

ReferenceError: ExtRemote is not defined

Ext.direct.Manager.addProvider(ExtRemote.REMOTING_API);

unfortunately on internet I did not find many examples nor resources to learn how to use extdirect with node.js, so now I am stuck, can you point me to the right way with tutorials examples etc. THanks

Answer (score 1):

After reading [extdirect](https://npmjs.org/package/extdirect) documentation and a somewhat related [thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?243355-Ext-Direct-resource-assumes-static-api) I recognized the definition ExtRemote.REMOTING_API comes from the server at /directapi wwhich serves something like

```
Ext.ns("ExtRemote");ExtRemote.REMOTING_API={"url":"http://...
```

hence what needs to be in index.html, maybe should be emphasized better in documentation, is a script import like

```
<script src="/directapi"></script>
```

In Sencha Architect that can be added to a project's Resources as a JS Resource.

That took care of the ReferenceError: ExtRemote is not defined.